# Add language path into browser address bar

Tags: javascript, php

I'm looking for information about adding extra information into browser address bar. for example language path.

So what type of code should I look for if I wanna change browser address from **mysite.com/index.php** to **mysite.com/EN/index.php**

but at the same time, I don't have to make an extra folder for each language file what I add for the website.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which web server is hosting the application. If apache, a way to get this is using `AliasMatch` directive. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch. This applies to `httpd.conf` (global apache configuration file) or `.htaccess` (local apache configuration file) and requires `mod_alias`.

Example:

`AliasMatch "^/(EN|FR|PT)/(.*)"   "/local/path/$2"`

will accept /EN/... /FR/... and /PT/... .

or

`AliasMatch "^/([A-Z]{2})/(.*)"   "/local/path/$2"`

will accept any two upper case letters as prefix.

After getting this working, in order to determine which language to show, you should check `$_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]` variable in your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to handle this on the server side. When a request is made to `mysite.com/EN/index.php`, the server checks the request URL for the language part `EN` and serves a webpage with the corresponding language from wherever it resides in the file structure.

Comment: Well you need to be more specific in terms of what technologies you are using and what exactly you want to achieve. 1) What kind of server are you using? Is it part of a website building service? Is it something like apache/nginx? Are you serving files from a web application you're building using something like express for node.js? 2) What exactly do you mean by "change browser address"? Do you simply need your website to be accessible using the `.../EN/...` URL instead of the simple one? Do you instead want to redirect users that use the simple URL to one that always contains a language code?

Comment: At this moment I'm using XAMPP web server on my local machine. 
And I wanna so the EN or US or LV is part of any page on the website. 
So yes I need **.../EN/...** to be accessible instead of simple one.

Comment: I haven't had much experience with XAMPP but since it uses Apache server, I suggest you take a look at [Matheus Neder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51010075/6046739) which in this case might be more useful than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the public folder in the hosting and create a new folder in it named EN and copy index.php to the folder EN and try the path mysite.com/EN/index.php .It should work.

Comment: Ok and if I have translated the site into 10 languages.
And I wanna do some changes for the header. Now I have to go into all 10 folders and change it all. It's not productive.

Comment: You can create header in the public file before EN folder and in each languages at top you can put include'../header.php'  which will make changes to each language page.